# NSStatusItem not shown after sleep

Tags: cocoa, macos

I've got a small Cocoa problem. I have a StatusBar application that has an NSStatusItem in the Menu Bar. It is drawn by a custom View as [shown here](http://telemeterx.vandenpoel.be/node/32). When the Main view of the app is hidden (most of the time), the computer goes to sleep and awakens again, I lose the icon and a blue rectangle is shown. Has anyone of you got any idea what I can do about it. It doesn't happen when the Main View is shown.

Comment: What code are you using to show the item? are you disposing the image somewhere when the application shuts down?

Comment: Thanks for asking me the question.
I used this,
  [theItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:[toolbarView frame] 
And because you asked I changed it to this
[toolbarView  setNeedsDisplay:YES]; 

I'm not 100% sure this fixes the problem. But I can't seem to reproduce it anymore.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it's fixed. But I'll give it to my testers and see if it pops back up. AlBlue, thanks for the hint !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by replacing  [theItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:[toolbarView frame]] to [toolbarView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
Thanks AlBlue for getting me in the right direction.